# Remove only one frequency of duplicate word from String array

Tags: java, string

I have a string array

```
String a = "This is a life and our life will be full of fun just like the Benn Steller's Secret life of Walter Mitty.";

String a1[]=a.split(" ");
for(String temp: a1)
{
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```

Here "life" is repeated three times. Now I have to remove only one frequency of duplicate word form array.

please guide me....

Thanks.

Comment: this is not an `Array`!!!

Comment: does this code even compile?. You will get String cannot be converted to String[] error

Comment: Not clear what you want to do here. It would help if you can post the final string you want. That would make it easier for us to answer

Comment: what do you mean about one frequency of duplicate?

Comment: Edit the question so it does not say a String array. Format the code a bit so people can see it better. Specify your issue (What's "one frequency of duplication"?) and __bold it__.

Comment: @aashish_soni you only want one instance of each string not duplicate?

Comment: is that a interview question?

Comment: @t8h7gu your answer is wrong cuz it removes the first life and keep the rest, and this question is kind of nonsense cuz of has been repeated as well ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this, but this will remove only first occurence of specified word:

Full code which removes one duplicate. You need to know that it doesn't ignore special characters, and space is delimiter in this case.

```
public static void main(String []args){
     String a = "This is a life and our life will be full of fun just like the Benn Steller's Secret life of Walter Mitty Mitty";
     System.out.println(removeOneDuplicate(a));
}

public static String removeOneWord(String str, String word){
    int value = str.indexOf(word);
    String result = str.substring(0, value);
    result += str.substring( value+word.length(), str.length());
    return result;
}

public static String removeOneDuplicate(String a){
    String [] tmp = a.split(" ");
     Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
     for(String s: tmp){
         if( map.containsKey(s)){
            int value = map.get(s); 
            if(value == 1)
                a = removeOneWord(a, s);
             map.put(s, value + 1);
         }
         else
             map.put(s, 1);
     }
     return a;
}
```

Sample results:

```
INPUT: This is a life and our life will be full of fun just like the Benn Steller's Secret life of Walter Mitty Mitty
OUTPUT: This is a  and our life will be full  fun just like the Benn Steller's Secret life of Walter  Mitty
```

In result You can see that `life`, `of` and `Mitty` is removed.

**EDIT**

If you want to remove all duplicates and leave first occurence of word change following lines:

`int value = str.indexOf(word);` -> `int value = str.lastIndexOf(word);`

```
int value = map.get(s); 
if(value == 1)
    a = removeOneWord(a, s);
map.put(s, value + 1);
```

to:

```
a = removeOneWord(a, s);
```

Comment: It's not answering the question. It removes a specified word, but not "one frequency of duplicate word", and definitely not duplicate.

Comment: could you explain what he meant by saying 
one frequency of duplicate ?

Comment: I hope this is what OP wanted.

Comment: the output is totally wrong because it removes a first life and keep the rest. It must keep the first and remove the rest.

Comment: It's very simple to acheive that, but I'm not sure if it is what OP's wanted. Remove `if(value == 1)` and change `str.indexOf(word)` to `str.lastIndexOf(word)` and you will get that.

Comment: where does "of" goes which was after "will be full" ?

Comment: It is removed because of  `Secret life of Walter` which holds second `of`.

Comment: @t8h7gu check out my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the example you provided is not a String array. It is a String.

I am giving the solution based on String. If you need it for String array, you will be able to do this on your own, if you understand this.

First, lets take a string tokenizer. A tokenizer breaks apart a string by a given character set. In its simplest form, it breaks apart a string by space.
For example, a string str = "This is a test". A simple tokenizer will break this string into words like "This" "is" "a" "test".

Below is the code to declare and use tokenizer:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(a); // a is given your string
```

Now, we declare an array of string below. (An array of string is an array, the element of each array is a single string.)

```
String[] str_arr = new String[100];
```

We will now use the tokenizer to get each word of your string and keep each words in the array of strings like below:

```
int index=0; // to keep track of index of the array (of strings)

while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
  str_arr[index] = (String) st.nextElement();
  index++;
}
```

So, now we have an array of strings named 'str_arr'. Now we will check for each element of the array whether duplicate values are occuring or not. If we find a duplicate, we will replace it with a null value. But, we will do it only once. The remaining duplicates will be kept as it is, this is what you asked for, right?

To keep track of a string already searched and made null, we will use a HashMap like this.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> hash_map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Now, we will run 2 nested loops and after that, we will have a modified array where only multiple occurrence of a string is reduced by 1.

```
for(int i=0; i<index; i++){

            String current_string = str_arr[i];

            for(int j=i+1; j<index; j++){
                if( (current_string.equals(str_arr[j])) && (hash_map.containsKey(current_string)==false) && str_arr[j]!=""){
                    hash_map.put(str_arr[j], 1);
                    str_arr[j]="";
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
```

Now, you can print all the words simply as below:

```
for(int i=0; i<index; i++)
System.out.print(str_arr[i]+" ");

INPUT: This is a life and our life will be full of fun just like the Benn Steller's Secret life of Walter Mitty.
OUTPUT: This is a life and our  will be full of fun just like the Benn Steller's Secret life  Walter Mitty.
```

Sorry for long explanation, but still if you can't get any point, please comment. I will try to reply. 
Thanks! 
Happy Coding :)

Comment: how were you able to keep all life and just remove ofs?

Comment: About "life" => I removed 1 life from the 3 occurrences , About "of" => I removed 1 of from the 2 occurrences. This is what you asked for, right?

Comment: but your output showed the difference. could u check out my answer too? but I didn't remove any of cuz the question doesn't ask :)

Answer (score 0):

As we know, set does not contain duplicate at all.

My Code:

```
 String a = "This is a life and our life will be full of fun just like the Benn     Steller's Secret life of Walter Mitty.";
        String[] aSpilt = a.split(" ");

        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(aSpilt);
        System.out.print("The input is : ");
        list.forEach((s) -> System.out.print(s + " "));
        System.out.println();
        Set<String> noDuplicateSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        Set<String> duplicateSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();

        list.forEach((i) -> {
            if (!noDuplicateSet.add(i) && i.equals("life")) {
                duplicateSet.add(i + " ");
            }
        });
        System.out.print("The output is : ");
        noDuplicateSet.forEach((s) -> System.out.print(s + " "));
        System.out.println("");
        duplicateSet.forEach((s) -> System.out.print(s + " "));
```

My output:

```
The input is : This is a life and our life will be full of fun just like the Benn Steller's Secret life of Walter Mitty. 
The output is : This is a life and our will be full of fun just like the Benn Steller's Secret Walter Mitty
```

Note:

1. I kept the first life and remove the rest, and of was encountered more than once which I did not touched because the question wants just to keep first life and remove the rest.
2. I used lambda expression to traverse collections

Sources:

1. http://www.programcreek.com/2013/03/hashset-vs-treeset-vs-linkedhashset/
2. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String  s;
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    s=in.nextLine();
    String ch[]=s.split(" ");
    String m=in.nextLine();
    for(int i=;i<ch.length;i++)
    {
        if(ch[i].matches(m))
            ch[i]="";

        S.o.p(ch[i]);
    }
}
```